# Background blur в CSS без backdrop-filter

Tags: css, вёрстка

Хочу добиться частично прозрачного фона для сайдбара с применением blur-эффекта. Сейчас использую свойство `backdrop-filter` для этих целей, и все работает отлично (в хроме):
[image: Пример]

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) !important;
backdrop-filter: blur(24px);
```

[Но поддержка этого свойства между браузерами довольно слабая](https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter).

Собственно, отсюда и вопрос: а можно ли добиться подобного эффекта с поддержкой большего количества браузеров? Интересуют хотя бы последние версии chromium/firefox/safari.

Гугл в основном выдает информацию только по поводу изображений. Мне это не очень подходит, поскольку у меня просто полупрозрачный белый фон, а не изображения.

Comment: Если фон равномерно прозрачен, может сохранить полупрозрачный png-файл и его выбрать в качестве фона?

Comment: Если на фоне только карта и она рисуется на канвасе, то можно найти функцию блура канваса и ставить его на фон меню. Или блурить изображение из канваса обычным css-блуром и ставить его внутрь меню, но тогда по его краям будут прозрачные области.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Там WebGL сцена, рисуемая сторонней библиотекой. Не уверен, что хочу туда лезть. Тем более, ничего в WebGL не понимаю. Как-то пытался просто квадрат отрисовать - даже это сделать не удалось, слишком много действий это требует. Кроме того, ширину сайдбара изменять можно. Придется следить за шириной и соответственно обновлять канвас.

Comment: @Quazimorda звучит как костыль (ИМХО). Не проверял, но, почему-то, уверен, что будут проблемы с сопряжением блюров между картинками (границы размытости будут накладываться друг на друга).

Comment: Туда лезть и не нужно. Возьмите оттуда итоговое изображение из канваса, даже не всё, а нужный кусок, и с ним работайте. Его можно заблурить обычным css-блуром или загнать в свой канвас и блурить самостоятельно, если не хотите чтобы края были прозрачные и найдёте такой блур где-то или сами напишете.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev вы имеете в виду брать "снэпшот" того, что отрендерено на канвасе, обрезать это под размер сайдбара и ставить это изображение в качестве фона сайдбара, применяя нужные фильтры?

Comment: @smellyshovel Строго говоря и я не проверял, но о наложении каких границ размытости вы говорите? У вас внизу карта, сверху полупрозрачный и отчасти размытый фон у меню. А что ещё на что должно накладываться? Впрочем, в моём варианте речь идёт в первую оченредь про полупрозрачность. Размытия так как такового нет.

Comment: Да. Только не как фон в css ставить, а например как элемент с обычным фильтром блура. Или взять этот кусок изображения, поместить в свой канвас, дополнить его по всем сторонам повторами пикселей и применить обычный блур. Тогда даже по краям будет годно.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev как вариант. Я так понимаю, ничего стандартного безхакового для этих целей не предусмотрено. Вот только, мне кажется, в плане производительности хромать будет такое решение. В любом случае, спасибо за идею.

Comment: Нормальное решение вряд ли есть, этот фильтр и придуман относительно недавно потому что не было ничего нормального. Это частая проблема была например для попапов когда под ними блурить нужно было страницу.

Comment: Поддержка 93.44% of tracked mobile и только растёт... Зачем что-то еще ‍♂️

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov да, возможно, лучшим решением будет просто подождать, пока выкатят в лису.